# Jhipster extented user entity and account creation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm building a job finding website using Jhipster.
Two of our main entities are '*candidate*' and '*headHunter*'
They're both users of the app, so they both have account on the app.

We decided to make each entities have a "one to one" relationship with User entity.

On top of that, we created a '*userCustom*' entity to manage commons fields.
This entity also have a "one to one" relationship with User.

So when either a headHunter or a candidate create a new account on the website, i have to call a "save" on 3 services : user, userCustom and candidate/headHunter

**My main problem is :** 
To create the userCustom and the candidate/headHunter, i need the userId.

What is the cleanest way to do this ?

Should I call the save on user, then call a get to retrieve the userId and then make the save on the two other entity ?

**Another more general question :** 
With this kind of configuration, is it a good idea to create custom DTO/services for each configuration (user,userCustom,candidate // user,userCustom,headHunter) ?
Or do i just need to customize my candidate and headHunter classes ?

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985742/jhipster-registering-a-user-with-additional-information maybe you are from same school :)

Comment: Thanks, it's similar yes, but the answer you gave him doesn't fully respond to my questions. I can use @MapsId and modify my database, but my issue is not solved.
ps: And no i'm not a student and i'm not on the same project ;)