# JHipster : Registering a user with additional information

Tags: jhipster

I am developping an application using JHispter 3.12.2.

Since I needed more information than what JHipster provides, I created an entity UserExtra containing two Strings : a phone number and a skype address.
I linked this entity to the JHI_User in a One to One relationship.

Now the problem I am facing is, when a user is registering, I want to create a new UserExtra associated with the registered User.

To achieve that, I have tried several things on the client side.

The way the standard JHipster register page works is by using a variable named vm.registerAccount that holds the firstName, lastName, login, password and so on.

I have tried using another variable vm.userExtra holding my phone number and skype. Then, I tried several things :

- In the register.controller.js, I passed my userExtra to the createAccount function :

  ```
  Auth.createAccount(vm.registerAccount, vm.userExtra).then(function () {
                      vm.success = 'OK';
                  }).catch(function (response) {
                      vm.success = null;
                      if (response.status === 400 && response.data === 'login already in use') {
                          vm.errorUserExists = 'ERROR';
                      } else if (response.status === 400 && response.data === 'e-mail address already in use') {
                          vm.errorEmailExists = 'ERROR';
                      } else {
                          vm.error = 'ERROR';
                      }
                  });
  ```
- I modified the createAccount function of auth.service.js to follow the changes made :

  ```
  function createAccount (account, userExtra, callback) {
              var cb = callback || angular.noop;
  ```

  ```
          return Register.save(account, userExtra,
              function () {
                  return cb(account);
              },
              function (err) {
                  this.logout();
                  return cb(err);
              }.bind(this)).$promise;
      }</pre>
  ```
- Finally, I updated the registerAccount function of AccountResource.java on the server side :

  ```
  public ResponseEntity registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody ManagedUserVM managedUserVM, UserExtra userExtra) { ... }
  ```

But the registerAccount function wasn't even executed from what I remember.

I also tried adding the new user in the callback of the createAccount function of register.controller.js like this :

```
Auth.createAccount(vm.registerAccount).then(function (result) {
                vm.userExtra.user = result;
                UserExtra.save(vm.userExtra, function() { // success }, function() { // fail });
                vm.success = 'OK';
            })...
```

But I was only getting an error while trying to save the new UserExtra.

I am pretty sure I need to modify the registerAccount() function inside AccountResource.java, but I just can't retrieve the additional information I am trying to send from the client side. I managed to create a new User inside this function and link it to the JHI_User, but without the additional information.

It's very likely somebody has already faced this issue, what could possibly be the best solution to that problem ?

**Edit with solution :**

Thanks to Gaël Marziou, I fixed my problem.

[Here's a minimal example of a project](https://github.com/Paul-Etienne/jhipster-userextra-example) using the solution I'm describing here.

On the client side, in the register.html page that I have rewritten to my use, I have two fields bound to vm.registerAccount properties :

```
<input class="form-control" id="phone" ng-model="vm.registerAccount.phone" placeholder="{{'global.form.phone.placeholder' | translate}}" />
...
<input class="form-control" id="skype" ng-model="vm.registerAccount.skype" placeholder="{{'global.form.skype.placeholder' | translate}}" />
```

In ManagedUserVM I really just added my two fields and their getters :

```
private String phone;

private String skype;

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getSkype() {
    return skype;
}
```

I changed my UserExtra class to map the User and UserExtra ids so that they are mirrored. This accelerates the retrieval process and makes more sense as UserExtra really is just an extension to User :

```
public class UserExtra implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "skype")
    private String skype;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

I created a new custom function called createUser() in UserService which needs my two fields in addition to the basic ones. I didn't update the existing function so that I don't have to change the test classes :

```
public User createUser(String login, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email,
                       String langKey, String phone, String skype) {

    User newUser = new User();
    Authority authority = authorityRepository.findOne(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);
    Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    newUser.setLogin(login);
    // new user gets initially a generated password
    newUser.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
    newUser.setFirstName(firstName);
    newUser.setLastName(lastName);
    newUser.setEmail(email);
    newUser.setLangKey(langKey);
    // new user is not active
    newUser.setActivated(false);
    // new user gets registration key
    newUser.setActivationKey(RandomUtil.generateActivationKey());
    authorities.add(authority);
    newUser.setAuthorities(authorities);
    userRepository.save(newUser);
    userSearchRepository.save(newUser);
    log.debug("Created Information for User: {}", newUser);

    // Create and save the UserExtra entity
    UserExtra newUserExtra = new UserExtra();
    newUserExtra.setUser(newUser);
    newUserExtra.setPhone(phone);
    newUserExtra.setSkype(skype);
    userExtraRepository.save(newUserExtra);
    userExtraSearchRepository.save(newUserExtra);
    log.debug("Created Information for UserExtra: {}", newUserExtra);

    return newUser;
}
```

Finally, I updated the registerAccount() function of AccountResource to call my custom function using the two additional fields :

```
public ResponseEntity<?> registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody ManagedUserVM managedUserVM) {

    HttpHeaders textPlainHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    textPlainHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    return userRepository.findOneByLogin(managedUserVM.getLogin().toLowerCase())
        .map(user -> new ResponseEntity<>("login already in use", textPlainHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))
        .orElseGet(() -> userRepository.findOneByEmail(managedUserVM.getEmail())
            .map(user -> new ResponseEntity<>("e-mail address already in use", textPlainHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                User user = userService
                    .createUser(managedUserVM.getLogin(), managedUserVM.getPassword(),
                        managedUserVM.getFirstName(), managedUserVM.getLastName(),
                        managedUserVM.getEmail().toLowerCase(), managedUserVM.getLangKey(),
                        managedUserVM.getPhone(), managedUserVM.getSkype());

                mailService.sendActivationEmail(user);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
            })
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paul-Etienne, I just saw your tip on the jhipster site. One question: Would you mind uploading a minimal complete example of this on github or something similar? I tried the same having a Postgresql database and newest jhipster with --skip-client option, here but it wouldn't work, and now i'm asking myself if I am missing something, like "do I need to declare `@OneToOne` in the user entity too? Are the entities created with the generator or by hand? Does the UserExtra entity need `@Entity` annotation" and questions like this. Would be great!

Comment: Hi @getoverit-DE, I won't have time today to really look into your request, but I should have time to do it tomorrow.

Comment: hi @Paul-Etienne, this would be absolutely great, thank you!

Comment: @getoverit-DE I've just created a minimal project as you requested, here's the [link](https://github.com/Paul-Etienne/jhipster-userextra-example).
While recreating this, I realized there's a detail I didn't mention in my tip, after updating the UserExtra entity with the "MapsId" annotation, you also have to edit manually its liquibase changelog to take this change into account. You'll see by yourself if you look at the code in the example projet.
I'm editing my original question to include the sample project.

Comment: I just added a new [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343572/jhipster-4-14-1-registering-a-user-with-additional-information) for the same problem in JHipster 4.14.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ManagedUserVM` is a view model so simplest way is to add your extra fields to it, a view model can be an aggregate of several entities. This way you don't change your angular service, your client code does not need to know how a User is stored on server.

Then on server, you should consider modifying the `UserExtra` entity to use same id as `User` rather than a generated id, use `@MapIds`. See this very [nice article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I didn't mention it in my original post, but I had already tried to add the fields in ManagedUserVM. Looks like the only thing I was missing was mapping the ids, I didn't even know that was possible.
I just have one interrogation now, how does the server knows what fields to populate according to what the client sends ? I really just added the fields and their getters, no special constructor. Is it only because the fields names match ?

Comment: Probably but it should be verified. Could you show some code? I also think it should be very useful to share this as a tip on https://jhipster.github.io/tips/

Comment: Okay, I just have one more problem I want to fix before showing the complete working code and making a pull request on the tip section of JHipster. I can retrieve my phone number and skype account in the registerAccount() function of AccountResource.java but am struggling to save them in my database. I'll work on it and reach back to you when it's solved.

Comment: Alright, I kind of worked around my problem here, I didn't use the @MapIds as you suggested, even though I agree it would be better with. I edited my question to provide the solution directly. Do you think this solution is acceptable enough to make a pull request in the JHipster tips ? (even though the ids aren't mirrored)

Comment: Regarding `@MapIds` exception, it could be due to not being enrolled in same transaction which could be solved by annotating registerAccount() with `@Transactional` but a better way could be to move most of your code to the service layer which is transactional.

Comment: You're right, it's working now. I've moved the code creating the UserExtra to a custom createUser() function of UserService which is transactional. I think the solution is perfect now :) I'm updating the solution and will create a pull request for a tip. Thank you very much for your help that proved more than useful.

Comment: You did a great job

Comment: @GaëlMarziou would be great if you could have a look for my comment under the main question. and thanks for the great work regarding jhipster!