# JHipster: Registering a user with additional information

Tags: jhipster

**First of all, I'd like to thank "*[Paul Etienne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6527252/paul-etienne)*" for his helpful [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985742/jhipster-registering-a-user-with-additional-information)! The answer bellow is a little bit more detailed and has been written considering the last version of JHipster (3/17/2018).**

The question is clear: how to add new data field(s) to User entity in a JHipster project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As it's mentioned in the official JHipster website, the best way to add new fields/relations to the default JHipster User is creating a new Entity and link it to User with a one-to-one relationship. You may handle more relationships in the new Entity. Let's call this new Entity UserExtra.
[image: Composition between User and UserExtra]

The UML diagram above, shows a composition between User and UserExtra meaning that a User has a UserExtra which is strongly dependent to the User and cannot exist without the User. In other words, there should be a user first so we can assign a phone number to.

**Step 1: Creating a new entity**

I suggest creating the new entity using terminal: jhipster entity userExtra

or

JDL:

[image]

**Step 2: Modifying the new entity**

You may find the new entity class under the domain folder:
[image]

We may map the id of UserExtra to the id of User so we can use the id of UserExtra as the foreign-key. If so, then we should not use @GeneratedValue annotation for id in UserExtra anymore. Here is a sample UserExtra class. Here is a sample of a modified UserExtra:

```
package org.jhipster.domain;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A UserExtra.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_extra")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class UserExtra implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public UserExtra phone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
        return this;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public UserExtra user(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        UserExtra userExtra = (UserExtra) o;
        if (userExtra.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), userExtra.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserExtra{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", phone='" + getPhone() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Modifying the configuration of the new entity**

[You may skip this step if you've used JDL in the 1st step]

There is a json file keeping the configuration of the entity:
[image]
We need to modify the configuration. here is a sample of a modified configuration json file:

```
{
    "fluentMethods": true,
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
            "relationshipName": "user",
            "otherEntityName": "user",
            "otherEntityField": "id",
            "ownerSide": true,
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "userExtra"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "phone",
            "fieldType": "String"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20180317190851",
    "dto": "no",
    "service": "no",
    "entityTableName": "user_extra",
    "jpaMetamodelFiltering": false,
    "pagination": "no"
}
```

There are also some xml change logs:
[image]
Here are sample change logs:

added_entity_UserExtra:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql"/>
    <!--<property name="autoIncrement" value="true"/>-->

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle, mssql"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity UserExtra.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20180317190851-1" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="user_extra">
            <column name="user_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="phone" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>

            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here, do not remove-->
        </createTable>

    </changeSet>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changeset - JHipster will add changesets here, do not remove-->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

added_entity_constraints_UserExtra:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
    <!--
        Added the constraints for entity UserExtra.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20180317190851-2" author="jhipster">

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="user_id"
                                 baseTableName="user_extra"
                                 constraintName="fk_user_extra_user_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="jhi_user"/>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Just be aware that JHipster uses a table named "JHI_USER" for the User entity and has created a table named "USER_EXTRA" for the new entity. We are going to name the primary-key/id field of the new entity "USER_ID":

[image]

**Step 4: Modifying ManagedUserVM.java**

ManagedUserVM class is sort of a DTO extending UserDTO which is used in the REST controller.
[image]

The purpose of this modification is adding the new field(s) we are going to bind to User as extra information. Here is a sample code of this class. The phone attribute has been added to the modified class:

```
package org.jhipster.web.rest.vm;

import org.jhipster.service.dto.UserDTO;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 * View Model extending the UserDTO, which is meant to be used in the user management UI.
 */
public class ManagedUserVM extends UserDTO {

    public static final int PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 4;

    public static final int PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 100;

    @Size(min = PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH, max = PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH)
    private String password;
    private String phone;

    public ManagedUserVM() {
        // Empty constructor needed for Jackson.
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ManagedUserVM{" +
            "} " + super.toString();
    }
}
```

**Step 5: modifying UserService.java**

There is a method named "registerUser" in this calss which is responsible for registering a new user:

[image]

The purpose of modifying this service class is to force it to also add a UserExtra object when a User is getting added. here is a sample of a modified "registeruser" method. You may find the added code with "Create and save the UserExtra entity" at top of it as comment:

```
public User registerUser(UserDTO userDTO, String password, String phone) {

        User newUser = new User();
        Authority authority = authorityRepository.findOne(AuthoritiesConstants.USER);
        Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
        newUser.setLogin(userDTO.getLogin());
        // new user gets initially a generated password
        newUser.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
        newUser.setFirstName(userDTO.getFirstName());
        newUser.setLastName(userDTO.getLastName());
        newUser.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        newUser.setImageUrl(userDTO.getImageUrl());
        newUser.setLangKey(userDTO.getLangKey());
        // new user is not active
        newUser.setActivated(false);
        // new user gets registration key
        newUser.setActivationKey(RandomUtil.generateActivationKey());
        authorities.add(authority);
        newUser.setAuthorities(authorities);
        userRepository.save(newUser);
        cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE).evict(newUser.getLogin());
        cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE).evict(newUser.getEmail());
        log.debug("Created Information for User: {}", newUser);

        // Create and save the UserExtra entity
        UserExtra newUserExtra = new UserExtra();
        newUserExtra.setUser(newUser);
        newUserExtra.setPhone(phone);
        userExtraRepository.save(newUserExtra);
        log.debug("Created Information for UserExtra: {}", newUserExtra);

        return newUser;
    }
```

**Step 6: modifying AccountResource.java**

This class is a REST controller responsible for Account related activities:
[image]

There is a method named "registerAccount" in this controller that calls "registerUser" method of UserService class:

```
User user = userService.registerUser(managedUserVM, managedUserVM.getPassword());
```

We need to modify this line so we can pass the new field(s) to the method:

```
    @PostMapping("/register")
    @Timed
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody ManagedUserVM managedUserVM) {
        if (!checkPasswordLength(managedUserVM.getPassword())) {
            throw new InvalidPasswordException();
        }
        userRepository.findOneByLogin(managedUserVM.getLogin().toLowerCase()).ifPresent(u -> {throw new LoginAlreadyUsedException();});
        userRepository.findOneByEmailIgnoreCase(managedUserVM.getEmail()).ifPresent(u -> {throw new EmailAlreadyUsedException();});
        User user = userService.registerUser(managedUserVM, managedUserVM.getPassword(), managedUserVM.getPhone());
        mailService.sendActivationEmail(user);
    }
```

**Step 7: Modifying the user interface**

Finally, you need to add an input element into the html file:

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="phone" data-translate="global.form.phone">Phone number</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" #phone="ngModel" placeholder="{{'global.form.phone.placeholder' | translate}}"
                           [(ngModel)]="registerAccount.phone">
                </div>
```

Then, this is what you'll have in the registration page:

[image]

And here is the data layer:

JHI_USER

[image]

USER_EXTRA

[image]

P.S.

**The easiest way to do this is just adding a UserExtra entity with a one-to-one relation to User via JDL and adding a "userExtra" while creating a new user.**

Comment: Thanks for your help ! The tips from the jhipster website is not updated because they don't speak about modifying removing "id" column in the database for extraUser.

Comment: @CallisteHanriat
I'm glad it helped! Actually, the easiest way to do this is just adding an ExtraUser entity with a one-to-one relation via JDL. And, that's it! That's all we need I guess :) You may then handle the other needed requirements in the code if there's any other requirement. So, the fancy stuff like mapping the "id" data field and adding a "userExtra" while creating a new user are not really necessary but I thought it might be helpful to know how to do these stuff. I'm gonna modify the answer to make it clear that it could be even easier.