# JHipster 4.14.4 : Registering a user with additional information

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jhipster

Following the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343572/jhipster-4-14-1-registering-a-user-with-additional-information) I get an `org.hibernate.cfg.RecoverableException: Unable to find column with logical name: id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(user_extra) and its related supertables and secondary tables`. It doesn't matter, if I change the entries in the liquibase changelogs regarding "user_extra.user_id". Even if I erase the liquibase changelogs (without the initial_schema) and/or remove the h2-database ( with `./gradlew clean`) - every time I get the error.

The link mentioned above is close to [the tipp on the jhipster.tech documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html), so I think I am missing something, but I am searching since hours for my failure(s)...

How does jhipster know to map the `jhi_user.id` to `user_extra.user_id` (OneToOne) if there is no explicit declaration for this in `UserExtra.json`? Is the declaration in the domain object `UserExtra.java` with
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private User user;
enough to trigger it?
Can somebody give me a hint, where Spring Data JPA maps the `user_id` from the `user_extra`-table to the `@Id Long id` of the domain object `UserExtra`?

My code generated with JHipster 4.14.4 is [on github](https://github.com/Mesqualito/weddingplaner).

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify my questions above, if you like!

Nevertheless I have found my mistakes. Unfortunately, there are no additional ManyToMany-relationships to `UserExtra` mentioned in the [jhipster.tech-tipp](https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html) - I had to change the `user_extra.id` to `user_extra.user_id` not only in the liquibase-changelogs, but also in the domain classes, which are linked ManyToMany to Spring MVC domain class `UserExtra`!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and Based on Jochen Gebsattel's answer, this is what I did:

1. Update the 202xxxxx_**added_entity_constraints_UserExtra**.xml

where I had

`referencedColumnNames="id"
 referencedTableName="user_extra"`

I replaced by

`referencedColumnNames="user_id"
 referencedTableName="user_extra"`

`user_id` being the name of the column containing the foreign key, in my user_extra entity/table

2. Update the **UserExtra** class  (here again, replace **id** by **user_id**)

Where I had many to many relations with other entities, for example

```
 @JoinTable(name = "user_extra_store",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_extra_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
```

I replaced with

```
 @JoinTable(name = "user_extra_store",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_extra_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
```

*Note: If you created a new liquibase changelog file in step 1 (instead of update), don't forget to reference it in the master.xml*