# JHipster: Registering a user with additional information[help]

Tags: java, angular, spring, jhipster

I have been following 
[this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343572/jhipster-registering-a-user-with-additional-information) trying to add information to the user, everything went good untill I got to the part where I add the input field to the register.component.html, when I add the ngModel directive the page stops working, the password strenght no longer works and when I try to register a user I get registration failed and the following errors:

```
2019-12-10 16:31:18.875 ERROR 912 --- [ XNIO-1 task-14] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column "USEREXTRA0_.USER_ID" not found; SQL statement`select userextra0_.user_id as user_id8_25_, userextra0_.activo as activo1_25_, userextra0_.cod_p as cod_p2_25_, userextra0_.morada as morada3_25_, userextra0_.nif as nif4_25_, userextra0_.nome as nome5_25_, userextra0_.permiss_change as permiss_6_25_, userextra0_.telef as telef7_25_, userextra0_.user_permissions_id as user_per9_25_, userextra0_.user_profile_id as user_pr10_25_ from user_extra userextra0_ [42122-200]`
2019-12-10 16:31:18.876 ERROR 912 --- [ XNIO-1 task-14] dw.aop.logging.LoggingAspect             : Exception in dw.web.rest.UserExtraResource.getAllUserExtras() with cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement' and exception = 'could not prepare statement; SQL [select userextra0_.user_id as user_id8_25_, userextra0_.activo as activo1_25_, userextra0_.cod_p as cod_p2_25_, userextra0_.morada as morada3_25_, userextra0_.nif as nif4_25_, userextra0_.nome as nome5_25_, userextra0_.permiss_change as permiss_6_25_, userextra0_.telef as telef7_25_, userextra0_.user_permissions_id as user_per9_25_, userextra0_.user_profile_id as user_pr10_25_ from user_extra userextra0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement'
2019-12-10 16:31:18.878 ERROR 912 --- [ XNIO-1 task-14] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error
```

When I try to see my UserExtra entity I get an Internal Server Error.

[Here is my UserExtra table, I realize the ID field should be called User_Id but I did everything according to the guide and have no idea what went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL7uv.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend You to check your Liquibase script. Most probably the field is not defined in user extra table definition.