# Spring could not prepare statement because of a not found column

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jhipster, liquibase

I'm working with jhipster, I got the following jdl format:

[image]

I've made some modification on the domains that looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_account")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ClientAccount implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
private String phone;

@Column(name = "identity")
private String identity;

@Column(name = "referal")
private String referal;

@Column(name = "refered_by")
private String referedBy;

@OneToOne
@MapsId
private User user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientAccount")
private Set<Reputation> reputations = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientAccount")
private Set<Trip> trips = new HashSet<>();
```

and the reputations domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reputation")
public class Reputation implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "rate", nullable = false)
private Integer rate;

@Column(name = "comment")
private String comment;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("reputations")
private TransporterAccount transporterAccount;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("reputations")
private ClientAccount clientAccount;
```

The user domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String login;

@JsonIgnore
@NotNull
@Size(min = 60, max = 60)
@Column(name = "password_hash", length = 60, nullable = false)
private String password;

@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
private String firstName;

@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
private String lastName;

@Email
@Size(min = 5, max = 254)
@Column(length = 254, unique = true)
private String email;

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false)
private boolean activated = false;

@Size(min = 2, max = 10)
@Column(name = "lang_key", length = 10)
private String langKey;

@Size(max = 256)
@Column(name = "image_url", length = 256)
private String imageUrl;

@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "activation_key", length = 20)
@JsonIgnore
private String activationKey;

@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "reset_key", length = 20)
@JsonIgnore
private String resetKey;

@Column(name = "reset_date")
private Instant resetDate = null;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "jhi_user_authority",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})

@BatchSize(size = 20)
private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

The Transporter liquibase is mapped as follow:

```
   <changeSet id="20200218210800-1" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="client_account">
            <column name="user_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="first_name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="last_name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="phone" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="identity" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="referal" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="refered_by" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here, do not remove-->
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="20200218210800-2" author="jhipster">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="user_id"
                                 baseTableName="client_account"
                                 constraintName="fk_client_account_user_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="jhi_user"/>
    </changeSet>
```

and the reputations liquibase:

```
    <changeSet id="20200218210700-1-data" author="jhipster" context="faker">
    <loadData
              file="config/liquibase/fake-data/reputation.csv"
              separator=";"
              tableName="reputation">
        <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
        <column name="rate" type="numeric"/>
        <column name="comment" type="string"/>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-loadcolumn - JHipster (and/or extensions) can add load columns here, do not remove-->
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="20200218210700-2" author="jhipster">
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="transporter_account_id"
                             baseTableName="reputation"
                             constraintName="fk_reputation_transporter_account_id"
                             referencedColumnNames="user_id"
                             referencedTableName="transporter_account"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="client_account_id"
                             baseTableName="reputation"
                             constraintName="fk_reputation_client_account_id"
                             referencedColumnNames="user_id"
                             referencedTableName="client_account"/>
</changeSet>
```

Still I'm getting the following stacktrace error:

> select reputation0_.id as id1_14_, reputation0_.client_account_user_id
>   as client_a4_14_, reputation0_.comment as comment2_14_,
>   reputation0_.rate as rate3_14_,
>   reputation0_.transporter_account_user_id as transpor5_14_ from
>   reputation reputation0_ order by reputation0_.id asc limit ?
>   [42122-200] 2020-02-20 09:48:03.515 ERROR 23616 --- [  XNIO-1 task-7]
>   c.a.dropme.aop.logging.LoggingAspect     : Exception in
>   com.abdrid.dropme.service.ReputationQueryService.findByCriteria() with
>   cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
>   prepare statement' and exception = 'could not prepare statement; SQL
>   [select reputation0_.id as id1_14_,
>   reputation0_.client_account_user_id as client_a4_14_,
>   reputation0_.comment as comment2_14_, reputation0_.rate as rate3_14_,
>   reputation0_.transporter_account_user_id as transpor5_14_ from
>   reputation reputation0_ order by reputation0_.id asc limit ?]; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
>   prepare statement'

Comment: How do you perform request which gives you this exception?

Comment: The request is through The reputationRepository: reputationRepository.findAll()

Comment: Could you paste the full error? We can't the root cause in what you pasted. Have you restarted your app to apply your Lquibase migration?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou , You mean an mvn liquibase:migrate right ?

Comment: No, only running your app which runs liquibase at startup unless you enable no-liquibase spring profile.What about pasting full error?

Comment: the full stacktrace is uploaded to here: http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1582213470862.txt

Comment: Your exception says that columnt `CLIENT_ACCOUNT_USER_ID` is not present in table `REPUTATION`, which indeed is not present there. I suggest you check your relations between entities.

Comment: my H2 database says table Reputation has:

ID   RATE   COMMENT   TRANSPORTER_ACCOUNT_ID   CLIENT_ACCOUNT_ID

Comment: @htshame, as you can see my table contains CLIENT_ACCOUNT_ID and not CLIENT_ACCOUNT_USER_ID as passed in the hibernate query, Its a kind of desynchronization between liquibase and H2 ..

Comment: @zahma I don't think it's liquibase or H2 related. I suppose it's related to Hibernate mappings. Can you update your question and add `user` entity?

Comment: @htshame added, I refered myself to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343572/jhipster-registering-a-user-with-additional-information in order to extend user properties, I created the one to one relationship with both transporterAccount and clientAccount.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue ... I added a new Field in an Entity known as title (String) and jhipster entity sub-generator worked well enough ... got no issues

code got compiled and portal was also working - but when I tried listing the entity page - the ajax call gave 500 Http Status - with internal server as "prepared statement could not be created" ...

I did

> ./mvnw clean integration-test

and then ran the ./mvnw normally again. All the cached code was flushed and portal started working back.

Answer (score 0):

The table name you used, User, is a reserved keyword for H2 databases ?

First try to surround table name of User with double quotes. If it does not work, rename your table with a name like Employee.

There is a list of keywords that can't be used as identifiers (table names, column names and so on), unless they are quoted (surrounded with double quotes).

http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords