# jhipster: OneToOne-Relationship with jhi-User - how to involve the UserExtraRepository?

Tags: jhipster

In relationship to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343572/jhipster-4-14-1-registering-a-user-with-additional-information):

Can someone tell me how to get the `userExtraRepository` to the method `registerUser()` in Step 5 respectively into the service-class `UserService`? Do I have to make a `private final UserExtraRepository userExtraRepository` and take it into the Constructor as the second argument to be able to pass it to the method?

And furthermore, would it be the same for the `userExtraSearchRepository` mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985742/jhipster-registering-a-user-with-additional-information)?

Comment: Yes, you access repositories with the standard spring autowiring / dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to how Paul-Etienne has done it: [link](https://github.com/Paul-Etienne/jhipster-userextra-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pefrancois/userextra/service/UserService.java)