# Jhipster: Enabling a user to create objects that are automatically linked to their account

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm building a service to help people make good decisions.
As part of this, I need to take users through an onboarding flow where they create entities that describe their situation.

As they input the data, I want to be able to link these entities to one another, and also link the entities to the user.

To facilitate this, I investigated the following answers:

[Jhipster extented user entity and account creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984367/jhipster-extented-user-entity-and-account-creation)

[JHipster : Registering a user with additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985742/jhipster-registering-a-user-with-additional-information)

These haven't answered my question though my approach is similar.

I have created a user metadata object and linked it to the Jhipster user entity via JDL - now I need to find a way to get the logged in user, so that I can add a reference to that logged in user to the entities they have created.

I'm most of the way through and have taken guidance from the Jhipster code itself.

I have a method in a component, there are a number of questions I have.

```
company: Company;
project: Project;
team: Team;

account: Account;
user: User;
userMetadata: UserMetadata;

linkEntities() {

    // Question 1: Is this the right approach?
    // Find the logged in account, the user is linked to this
    this.accountService.identity().then(account => {
        this.account = account;
    });

    // Find the user for that account
    this.userService.find(this.account.login)
            .subscribe(res => this.user = res.body);

    // Find the metadata
    this.userMetadataService.find(this.user.id)
            .subscribe(res => this.userMetadata = res.body);

    // Question 2: These values are undefined
    // Is there something obvious I am missing that might explain why?
    console.log(this.account);
    console.log(this.user);
    console.log(this.userMetadata);

    // The company, project and team entities have been 
    // created and submitted in a previous function, 
    // here I update them with the references to one another
    this.company.employees.push(currentlyLoggedInUserMetadata)
    this.project.participants.push(currentlyLoggedInUserMetadata)
    this.team.members.push(currentlyLoggedInUserMetadata)

    this.company.teamOwners.push(this.team);
    this.company.companyProjects.push(this.project);

    this.project.implementingTeams.push(this.team);
    this.project.parentCompany = this.company;

    this.team.parentCompany = this.company;
    this.team.teamProjects.push(this.project);

    // And then send the updated entities to the api
    this.subscribeToCompanySaveResponse(this.companyService.update(this.company));
    this.subscribeToProjectSaveResponse(this.projectService.update(this.project));
    this.subscribeToTeamSaveResponse(this.teamService.update(this.team));
}
```

I'm lost on why the three console.logs above have errors. I have just set these three values just above the console.logs. I'm reasonably new to RxJS - is there something in the way observables work that might be causing this?

Ideally I would like there to be a globally available value for the logged in user kept within the user service (there's a private instance of account in the account service, but no user - should I just make the account publicly available where by default it's private?)

I'm uncertain on what the best approach or most 'jhipster' approach is to getting the one to one linked user <--> userMetadata object for the currently logged in user.

I'm also very aware that this is a large method that tries to do many things. Once I can confirm that the whole thing works, I'll refactor it to be more manageable.

If anyone has advice on this approach, has done something similar or knows why the account and user variables in particular are undefined (I ran the method while logged in as admin), I'd appreciate the insight!

Thanks in advance for any time and advice you might have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for the information Phobos, I have created an easy solution that works well.

I'll detail it below for others who might have this same issue in the future:

As at my current Jhipster version (5.7.2) - I have used the SecurityUtils helper to write a simple API endpoint to get the current logged in user (or more specifically, their metadata - this is an arbitrary entity with a 1-1 mapping to a Jhipster specific user entity).

I first added a method to the metadata entity repository:

```
/**
 * Spring Data  repository for the UserMetadata entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface UserMetadataRepository extends JpaRepository<UserMetadata, Long> {
    Optional<UserMetadata> findOneByUser(User user);
}
```

I use separate service classes, and so called the repository in the user metadata service class:

```
    /**
     * Get the user metadata object that is associated with the currently logged in user
     * @return an optional containing nothing, or the metadata object
     */
    public Optional<UserMetadata> getUserMetadataForCurrentUser() {

        Optional<UserMetadata> userMetadata = Optional.empty();

        Optional<User> currentUser = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().flatMap(userRepository::findOneByLogin);

        if (currentUser.isPresent()) {
            userMetadata = userMetadataRepository.findOneByUser(currentUser.get());
        }

        return userMetadata;
    }
```

Note that I have made it easier by putting most of the logic on the API so that the client can be as dumb as possible. I like smart APIs and dumb clients.

In the above I use securityUtils to get the login of the user, and then find the user metadata for that user by the login. The client should never have to ask for the actual user object.

I pass the Optional of type UserMetadata to the web layer, that uses Jhipster's ResponseUtil to either return the object within the optional, or an error:

```
    /**
     * GET  /user-metadata/me : get the user metadata of the current user.
     *
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the userMetadata, or with status 404 (Not Found)
     */
    @GetMapping("/user-metadata/me")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<UserMetadata> getUserMetadataForCurrentUser() {
        log.debug("REST request to get UserMetadata for current user");
        Optional<UserMetadata> userMetadata = userMetadataService.getUserMetadataForCurrentUser();
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(userMetadata);
    }
```

Then we go to the front end. In the userMetadata Angular service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserMetadataService {
    public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/user-metadata';

    currentUserMetadata: UserMetadata;

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
        this.getCurrentUserMetadata().subscribe(res => (this.currentUserMetadata = res.body));
    }

    getCurrentUserMetadata() {
        return this.http.get<IUserMetadata>(`${this.resourceUrl}/me`, { observe: 'response' });
    }

// Rest of File
```

I decided to set a globally available value so that my other components and services could just get the metadata variable and not have to call for it each time.
I created a method to call the new API endpoint, and consumed that method in the constructor so that the object is always available to the client.

I've tried to push complexity away from the downstream consumer as much as I can. The onboarding component I was initially asking about can now achieve the goal with three lines of code:

```
this.company.employees.push(this.userMetadataService.currentUserMetadata);
this.project.participants.push(this.userMetadataService.currentUserMetadata);
this.team.members.push(this.userMetadataService.currentUserMetadata);
```

The rest is hidden away in services and the api itself.

Hopefully others find this information useful.
I've tried to explain thoroughly because this was extremely confusing when I first dived in to the codebase. Jhipster does a lot of cool things for you, but in my case that actually led to a feeling of 'It happens with magic' vs 'I understand the mechanics of how this works'.

Now I have a better idea of how this particular functionality works!

Comment: Great stuff, glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

JHipster provides a Utility class called SecurityUtils. You can use this to access the current user's login or their JWT token.

```
SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin();
SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserJWT();
```

If you need other information for your purposes, you can use the UserRepository to retrieve the entire user object using the user's login retrieved using the SecurityUtils class.

```
UserRepository.findOneByLogin('usersLogin');
```

This exists on the API side, so there is no need to interrogate the account object on the front-end for what you are trying to achieve.

P.s. The reason you aren't able to console log the account information in your above code is because the promise that is retrieving that information hasn't been resolved yet - thus, the object is still null. You would have to put your console.log inside your promise resolution, i.e.

```
this.accountService.identity().then(account => {
    this.account = account;
    console.log(this.account);
});
```

The same approach is needed for the other requests.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. So you're suggesting (to paraphrase) that rather then doing all this work on the front end, I could write a quick API call to query the API and then pass that through to the front end? - I.E expose that api call, consume it via the user service for example (as it's getting the currently logged in user), and use that within my onboarding flow?

I will assume this to be the case and try to work something up, if the solution is good I'll post it here and tick this as the answer :) Thanks!